# How safe or dangerous it is to use "UserAgent" of the request to identify the origin of the request?

Tags: c#, .net, post, twilio, user-agent

I am developing an SMS service which sends SMS to the destination numbers using Twilio as an SMS provider. Twilio is suppose to send a POST request to my web service as and when the status of the message is updated (i.e., sent, delivered, etc).

In order to make sure that the POST request is not sent by anyone else than Twilio, I am validating UserAgent of the request as below.

```
    If ((HttpRequest)request.OriginalRequest).UserAgent.StartsWith("TwilioProxy/"))
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Currently I am getting "TwilioProxy/1.0" as User Agent in each of the POST action, where I believe the version number can be changed in future, so I have skipped it from validation.

Is it possible to receive a request with the same user agent (something starting to "TwilioProxy/") from any other origin than Twilio? Is it safe to rely on UserAgent for this type of verification?

Any inputs/ suggestions on this will be much helpful to me.

Thanks

Comment: It's incredibly easy to spoof that. I wouldn't even call it spoofing. Some browsers have had a configuration setting for that, where you could just enter any arbitrary string.

Comment: Yeah, it's utterly trivia to spoof the user agent. At best, this is security through obscurity, but it wouldn't take anybody very long to look at the difference between a successful request and a rejected request and conclude that maybe the user agent string might be a factor.

Comment: Good rule of thumb though, if the user agent string includes the substring "B1TCH3ZZZZZ!1!!", the client isn't really Napoleon Bonaparte.

Comment: There is a simple rule about software security approach which is  'Never trust client'.

Comment: :) I got the point.. UserAgent can't be trusted.. but I couldn't find anything else in the HttpRequest which tells me the origin of request. Even, HttpReferrer is empty in this case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As the comments have mentioned, it is trivial to spoof a header and since the UserAgent header for Twilio is very simple, then it is unreliable to rely on it.

However, if you are interested in validating that requests are made by Twilio then you need to check out how we [sign requests](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security#validating-requests) to ensure they are not malicious.

Here's how it works:

1. Turn on TLS on your server and configure your Twilio account to use HTTPS urls.
2. Twilio assembles its request to your application, including the final URL and any POST fields (if the request is a POST).
3. If your request is a POST, Twilio takes all the POST fields, sorts them by alphabetically by their name, and concatenates the parameter name and value to the end of the URL (with no delimiter).
4. Twilio takes the resulting string (the full URL with query string and all POST parameters) and signs it using HMAC-SHA1 and your AuthToken as the key.
5. Twilio sends this signature in an HTTP header called X-Twilio-Signature

Then to verify that this `X-Twilio-Signature` contains a valid signature, you need to do the following in your application:

1. Take the full URL of the request URL you specify for your phone number or app, from the protocol (https...) through the end of the query string (everything after the ?).
2. If the request is a POST, sort all of the POST parameters alphabetically (using Unix-style case-sensitive sorting order).
3. Iterate through the sorted list of POST parameters, and append the variable name and value (with no delimiters) to the end of the URL string.
4. Sign the resulting string with HMAC-SHA1 using your AuthToken as the key (remember, your AuthToken's case matters!).
5. Base64 encode the resulting hash value.
6. Compare your hash to ours, submitted in the X-Twilio-Signature header. If they match, then you're good to go.

Within our official libraries, we include a request validator that can do all of this for you. [There is an example of doing this in C# in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security?code-sample=code-validate-signature-of-request&code-language=cs&code-sdk-version=default).

Let me know if this helps at all.